# Is it possible to list SPM dependencies from code

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager

Is it possible to list all Swift Package Manager dependencies from Swift code? If yes, how?

Comment: Do you mean `swift package dump-package`?

Comment: Hmm yeah maybe but 1 I don't have any Package.swift (deps have been installed through the GUI of Xcode 13) and 2 I need it from code and I don't think this command would work on production